# OAuth dialog request - error

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

My bot is running on this port :

```
http://localhost:3979/api/messages
```

So far, i want to authenticate user using another controller. 
I am following this code here :

```
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot/Controllers/OAuthCallbackController.cs
```

So, in my case i am creting link for facebook this way  :

```
 private static string GetOAuthCallBack(ResumptionCookie resumptionCookie, string facebookOauthCallback)
        {
            var uri = GetUri(facebookOauthCallback,
                Tuple.Create("userId", TokenEncoder(resumptionCookie.UserId)),
                Tuple.Create("botId", TokenEncoder(resumptionCookie.BotId)),
                Tuple.Create("conversationId", TokenEncoder(resumptionCookie.ConversationId)),
                Tuple.Create("serviceUrl", TokenEncoder(resumptionCookie.ServiceUrl)),
                Tuple.Create("channelId", resumptionCookie.ChannelId),
                Tuple.Create("locale", resumptionCookie.Locale ?? "en")
                );
            return uri.ToString();
        }


       public static string GetFacebookLoginURL(ResumptionCookie resumptionCookie, string facebookOauthCallback)
            {
                var redirectUri = GetOAuthCallBack(resumptionCookie, facebookOauthCallback);
                var uri = GetUri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth",
                    Tuple.Create("client_id", FacebookAppId),
                    Tuple.Create("redirect_uri", redirectUri),
                    Tuple.Create("response_type", "code"),
                    Tuple.Create("scope", "public_profile,email"),
                    Tuple.Create("state", Convert.ToString(new Random().Next(9999)))
                    );

                return uri.ToString();
            }
```

This works properly. 
It redirects in my oauth method. Then, in my controller so far i have this :

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> OAuthCallback([FromUri] string userId, [FromUri] string botId, [FromUri] string conversationId, [FromUri] string channelId, [FromUri] string serviceUrl, [FromUri] string locale, [FromUri] string code, [FromUri] string state, CancellationToken token)
        {
            // Get the resumption cookie
            var address =  new Address
                (
                    // purposefully using named arguments because these all have the same type
                    botId: FacebookHelpers.TokenDecoder(botId),
                    channelId: channelId,
                    userId: FacebookHelpers.TokenDecoder(userId),
                    conversationId: FacebookHelpers.TokenDecoder(conversationId),
                    serviceUrl: FacebookHelpers.TokenDecoder(serviceUrl)
                );

            var resumptionCookie = new ResumptionCookie(userId: userId, botId : botId, conversationId : conversationId, channelId : channelId, serviceUrl : serviceUrl, locale : locale);

 var accessToken = await FacebookHelpers.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(resumptionCookie, code, SimpleFacebookAuthDialog.FacebookOauthCallback.ToString());
```

And then in this methods for exchanging token i have this :

```
public async static Task<FacebookAcessToken> ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(ResumptionCookie resumptionCookie, string code, string facebookOauthCallback)
        {
            var redirectUri = GetOAuthCallBack(resumptionCookie, facebookOauthCallback);
            var uri = GetUri("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token",
                Tuple.Create("client_id", FacebookAppId),
                Tuple.Create("redirect_uri", redirectUri),
                Tuple.Create("client_secret", FacebookAppSecret),
                Tuple.Create("code", code)
                );

            return await FacebookRequest<FacebookAcessToken>(uri);
        }


public async static Task<FacebookAcessToken> ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(ResumptionCookie resumptionCookie, string code, string facebookOauthCallback)
        {
            var redirectUri = GetOAuthCallBack(resumptionCookie, facebookOauthCallback);
            var uri = GetUri("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token",
                Tuple.Create("client_id", FacebookAppId),
                Tuple.Create("redirect_uri", redirectUri),
                Tuple.Create("client_secret", FacebookAppSecret),
                Tuple.Create("code", code)
                );

            return await FacebookRequest<FacebookAcessToken>(uri);
        }
```

In the end, http get request to facebook api :

```
 string json;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                json = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
```

But this throws an error :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "EY0nNXg3w9U"
   }
}
```

edit : First uri : `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=217820658623757&redirect_uri=http:%2f%2flocalhost:3979%2fapi%2fOAuthCallback%3fuserId%3dZGVmYXVsdC11c2Vy0%26botId%3dNDlnamdpamw3YTRpbmM4MjFj0%26conversationId%3dN2YzZDc5aTBkNjBjbGhkZm1j0%26serviceUrl%3daHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1NzU4MQ2%26channelId%3demulator%26locale%3den&response_type=code&scope=public_profile%2cemail&state=3554`

and the second ::

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token?client_id=217820658623757&redirect_uri=http:%2f%2flocalhost:3979%2fapi%2fOAuthCallback%3fuserId%3dWkdWbVlYVnNkQzExYzJWeTA1%26botId%3dTkRsbmFtZHBhbXczWVRScGJtTTRNakZqMA2%26conversationId%3dTjJZelpEYzVhVEJrTmpCamJHaGtabTFqMA2%26serviceUrl%3dYUhSMGNEb3ZMMnh2WTJGc2FHOXpkRG8xTnpVNE1RMg2%26channelId%3demulator%26locale%3den&client_secret=4e2729974c5dcd7409d64c64366db18c&code=AQBDFYQAlsryp_qINGLqpFICA5PafRkTsov3ANXPPgezsllDBiCQpAvooiepXlYEFzwOi1UVOaE1CHk_ZXJyp5k4mL_8pGDhzvVVxivBJiY4yJ8PLdkuRcGNu1jU3wHyijX1vs6Df1LOWbYiJfJxsXK243cjQPcfcqd59eUS_yns8FcqGRM1WBMvceYp-VXby9SjOVcqXgRH72hm1s4guv1AppQJ-lQU8YLDyALsrwvBeddzui3F57-NzVWgMAatgfm94NBW8MoTuRxvurWEOvnt03x3CGOIgRdMq0MKvpjYs9dZkioAILJD50C_qt3Jj0A
```

redirect_uri is identical in both cases ....
Any idea ??

Comment: Can you show both `redirect_uri`s?

Comment: I added them in the end of my post.

Comment: They are not identical.

Comment: So the first one is to facebook oauth dialog and the second is for graph ?? 
They should be that way ?

Comment: The user id is different between the two calls.

Comment: Paste both in notepad and compare them.

Comment: Hmm.. this problem is because i am using bot simulator. Not real facebook. What do you think ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133806/discussion-between-activ8-and-patrick-hofman).